# Why I get CORS error in server while using socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, iis, socket.io, cors

I'm getting CORS error in server but I'm not getting this error in local. My project is working in local but when I try to connect my socket.io api in server I'm getting this error in console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://my-web-site.com.tr/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=ORwXVX_'
> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

My api code is like this:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3200;

app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));

const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        allowedHeaders: ["*"],
        credentials: true
    }
}).of('/abcHub');

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("Connected: " + socket.id);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`Disconnect ${socket.id}`);
        
    });
});


const server = http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

My client code like this:

```
   <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src = "node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.min.js"></script>
   <script>
  
      $(document).ready(() => {
      const socket = io("https://my-web-site.com.tr/abcHub"); 

      });
   </script>
```

I wonder that why I don't get cors error in local but I get in server? If you have any question, you can ask. Thanks.

Comment: Did you run this command to install cors ?    npm install cors --save

Comment: @firatt_ yes I did.

Comment: Did you refer to this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/20058276

Answer (score 1):

I solved. The problem is that iis is not hosting node.js project without redirection. I upload iisnode to server and did redirection settings. Then project worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const http = require("http")
const cors = require("cors")
const { Server } = require("socket.io") 
const corsOptions = require("./config/corsOptions.js")

app.use(cors())
const server = http.createServer(app)

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001

const io = new Server(server , corsOptions )

server.listen(port,() => {
    console.log("server listening on ","3001")
})
```

where the `corsOptions` is

```
const corsOptions = {
    cors: {
        origin: "*"
    }
}
```

Comment: It is same result. It is working in local but give cors error in iis server.